# Python LXML Missing Closing Tag

Tags: python-3.x, xml, soap, lxml

I'm trying to match a XML script format. I'm missing a closing tag on uicc. How do I close this in my script using lxml?

This is what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="urn:hss">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:add>
<subscriberList>
   <subscriber name="Sub_Test_Profile_0000000003">
    <uiccList>
       <uicc imsi="313:78:0000000003" profile="100Mbps_Data">
       </uicc>
    </uiccList>
   </subscriber>
   <subscriber name="Sub_Test_Profile_0000000004">
    <uiccList>
       <uicc imsi="313:78:0000000004" profile="100Mbps_Data">
       </uicc>
    </uiccList>
   </subscriber>
</subscriberList>
</ns2:add>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is where I am now:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="urn:hss">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:add>
      <subscriberList>
        <subscriber name="Sub_Test_Profile_0000000002">
          <uiccList>
            <uicc imsi="313:78:0000000002" profile="100Mbps_Data"/>

          </uiccList>
        </subscriber>
        <subscriber name="Sub_Test_Profile_0000000003">
          <uiccList>
            <uicc imsi="313:78:0000000003" profile="100Mbps_Data"/>

          </uiccList>
        </subscriber>
      </subscriberList>
      <uiccList/>
      </ns2:add>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
      </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

You can see the extra slash at the end of uicc. I need it to be `</uicc>`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed enough code to reproduce your issue. If I parse your "this is what I want" XML (etree.fromstring()) and then serialize it (etree.tostring()) I don't get any [self closing tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EmptyElemTag). Are you creating the XML? Are you parsing an existing XML? How are you serializing the XML?

Comment: @DanielHaley is correct, of course, that you should post a [mcve].  You also shouldn't care whether your elements use self-closing tags for empty elements.  Having said all that, see duplicate link if you still want to see how to affect lxml's serialization in this area.